# How to establish new connection through proxy using Squid in Python script?

Tags: proxy, python, squid

I am new to networking and proxy. For a project I need to give a proxy connection.

I already have a connection and I want change the connection behavior of the process to connect through that proxy. I would also like it to use a new IP in the event that it detects that it has been throttled.

The new connection process that I want is: connect from our server -> proxy -> required site if we are throttled: establish new connection through proxy (need to confirm new IP is being allocated by the proxy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this piece of code

```
proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': '127.0.0.1:8080'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long but it is expected.